# Empty files generated from running `mysqldump` using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting empty files generated from running

```
$command = 'mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u username -p \'password\' dbname > \'backup 2009-04-15 09-57-13.sql\'';

command($command);
```

Anyone know what might be causing this? My password has strange characters in it, but works fine with connecting to the db.

I've ran `exec($command, $return)` and outputted the $return array and it is finding the command. I've also ran it with `mysqldump > file.sql` and the file contains

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

So it would seem like the command is working.

Comment: Does it happen if you run it from the shell?

Comment: Ah.. I've got the solution now. Thanks anyway Paolo...

Comment: A downvote? hmmm... Can someone point out my error?

Comment: I have no clue why someone would downvote this or vote to close.  Maybe an excessively strict opinion that it's "not programming related" since it's about shell-level usage?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Remove the space** between `-p` and the password. If it didn't work, try to remove the quotes from the password

from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password):

> If you use the short option form (-p), you **cannot** have a space between the option and the password.

however, it is fine to have space with `-h` and `-u` options

Answer (score 5):

I believe there are no spaces between -u and the actual username.

```
host: localhost user: peter password: pwd
```

would become:

```
-hlocalhost -upeter -ppwd
```

Comment: There can be a space between -u and the user name because user names cannot include spaces.  There must NOT be a space between -p and the password because password because passwords CAN include spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have done it - output is with maximum gzip compression:

```
<?php exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=MYSQLHOSTNAME --user=MYSQLUSER --password=PASSWORD DATABASENAME | gzip -v -9 >DATABASENAME.". date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql.gz");?>
```

Comment: I almost implemented it the same way, though I had to specify the exact pathing on the server, which the cronjob needed in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in plain english, *make sure* to use the following options (all of them).
--user=USERNAME
--host=localhost
--password=****

The next non-option phrase should be your database name. If the command is followed by another non-option phrase, it will be treated as table names.

```
$command="mysqldump --xml --host=localhost --user=USERNAME --password=***** DBNAME > XMLTABLE.xml";
system($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$command = 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --opt --user=root --host=localhost --password="password" my_db'.' > '.$backupdate.$sql_file_name; exec($command);
```

I faced the same issue and got it fixed by quoting the password. For example --password="yourpassword".

Answer (score 0):

I had empty files too using mysqldump.
I run WampServer PHP7 under Windows 10.

```
system('mysqldump .... ') ;
```

Doen't work.
I had to add the full path (or add an Environment variable) :

```
system('C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin\mysqldump.exe ...') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **full path** to mysqldump:

```
// Linux:
$command = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u username -p \'password\' dbname > \'backup 2009-04-15 09-57-13.sql\'';

// Windows:
$command = 'c:\mysql\bin\mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u username -p \'password\' dbname > \'backup 2009-04-15 09-57-13.sql\'';
```